# Character assignment in c++

Tags: c++, char, variable-assignment

I am doing the following assignment in C++. I have an array of chars

```
char myyear[4] = { dob[0], dob[1], dob[2], dob[3] };
char mymonth[2] = {dob[4], dob[5]};
char mydate[2] = { dob[6], dob[7] };
```

and I wrote:

```
cout<<myyear<<"-"<<mymonth<<"-"<<mydate<<"-"<<endl;
```

and I got the output

```
1981╕■#-051981╕■#-02051981╕■#
```

and not

```
1981-05-02
```

which is what dob contains.

Any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include *null terminators* at the end of each of your character arrays.

For example,

```
char myyear[5] = { dob[0], dob[1], dob[2], dob[3], 0 };
```

`cout` (along with many other string-type functions in C and C++) requires a string to be modelled as a sequence of characters terminated by a 0.

What you are doing at the moment is, technically, *undefined behaviour*: the fact that you are getting any output at all is to be considered entierly coincidental.

By the way, why are you modelling the numeric values like this? `std::cout` also works for integer types: e.g. `int myyear = 1981; cout << myyear;` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need a `\0` (null termination) at the end.

```
char myyear[5] = { dob[0], dob[1], dob[2], dob[3], '\0' };
char mymonth[3] = {dob[4], dob[5], '\0'};
char mydate[3] = { dob[6], dob[7], '\0'};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to null terminate each of the arrays. See [character sequences](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/)

```
const char NULL_TERMINATOR = '\0';
char myyear[5] = { dob[0], dob[1], dob[2], dob[3], NULL_TERMINATOR };
char mymonth[3] = {dob[4], dob[5], NULL_TERMINATOR };
char mydate[3] = { dob[6], dob[7], NULL_TERMINATOR };
```